# When I click on the button show more information in the same page javascript

Tags: javascript, html

```
  <a href="#"  class="button">Read More</a><br>
```

I have this button on the website I don't know how to program the button that when I click `Read more` show me the information of the cd that I am selling.

Can you give me an idea how can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. There is a lot you can do with JavaScript, e.g- redirect the user to a different page, show a div temporarily to the user, show a blocking dialog box etc. You need to provide more information as to what exactly you want to do. You may edit the question and add more details of what you want for an accurate answer.

Comment: u can use jqurey tool tip. http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style

Answer (score 3):

You can use [JQuery](http://jquery.com/) which is a really nice framework to make the coding easy!

You want to use the [.click()](http://api.jquery.com/click/) event and the [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) function

So you could have something like this

```
$("#clickme").click(function() {
     $("#hidden").show();
});
```

and for your html

```
<html>
<body>
<p id="clickme">Read More</p>
<p id="hidden" hidden>COOL STORY BRO</p>
</body>
</html>
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Zf3RR/)

Answer (score -1):

```
Suppose you have,

<div id="dvInfo">
 Here is your question and i am giving an answer. 
</div>
<a href="javascript:void()" id='see'>See more</a>

So,
In jQuery

$(document).ready(function(){
  var f_text = $('#dvInfo').html();
  $('#dvInfo').html($('#dvInfo').html().substring(0,8)+"...");
  $('#see').click(function(){
   $('#dvInfo').html(f_text);
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

***html part***

`<asp:Button ID="btnread" runat="server" Text="Button" />
    <div id="divinfo" style="display:none">More Info</div>`

***jquery part:***

```
    $(function () {
        $("#<%=btnread.ClientID %>").click(function () {
            $("div[id$=divinfo]").css("display", "block");
            return false;
        });
    });
```